# How do I get modified date from file in C# on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-mobile

I make a file in PC, and I want to transfer it to a [PPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_PC) ([Windows Mobile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile)).

How can I get the modified date of this file?

(I need it on Windows Mobile.)

Answer (score 95):

[`FileInfo.LastWriteTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime.aspx) 
and 
[`FileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetimeutc.aspx) should register this information.

Comment: You can also use File.GetLastWriteTime and File.GetLastWriteTimeUTC

Comment: thank's for the answer, but it give me always the today date and time,  whay ?

Comment: If you are reading this attribute from the file that was just created (the copy), it will have today's date/time since the copy is considered a modification.  However, the source file shouldn't exhibit this behavior.

Perhaps you are looking for another file attribute?

Comment: Copying a file does not change date modified in my case. Windows 7

Comment: Microsoft Docs notes: "This method may return an inaccurate value, because it uses native functions whose values may not be continuously updated by the operating system." [File.GetLastWriteTime(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getlastwritetime?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Answer (score 33):

```
string strFilePath = @"C:\myfile.txt";
DateTime lastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(strFilePath);
```

**Reference:**  `File.GetLastWriteTime` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx).

Comment: straight forward

Comment: @DanielB Thanks! I'm always about doing the easiest path!

Answer (score 8):

Try This.

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("path");
var created = fileInfo.CreationTime; //File Creation
var lastmodified = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;//File Modification
```