# Fastest way to convert image to ARGB Array

Tags: c#, arrays, image, argb

i want to create an application that delete the duplicated photo in some folder so i need to convert an image to an ARGB array [one diemnsion] then compare them .
What is the fastest way to convert an Image to ARGB array?
or how to improve this code ?

```
 Image img;
 using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(imagefile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                img = Image.FromStream(stream);
            }

 using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img))
            {
                int[] argb = new int[bmp.Width * bmp.Height];
                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                {

                    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                    {

                        Color pxl = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

                        argb[x * y] = pxl.ToArgb();



                    }
                }
              }
```

Comment: You'll want to be using LockBits() to lock a whole region in memory rather than GetPixel(), which is comparatively inefficient.

Comment: how to do it could you give me an example please

Comment: Examples are readily available in the MSDN documentation for the Bitmap class.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1qpiUzc

Comment: @MeirionHughes, that's awesome.

Comment: If you're looking to compare files for exact duplicates could just use a hashing function (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520048/calculate-md5-checksum-for-a-file/10520086#10520086)

Comment: @rsbarro files may have different md5 but same ARGB color array ,isn't it?

Comment: @user3749485, theoretically, yes.  But if you know enough about the process by which the duplicates were created to say, for instance, that they're just the product of a file copy operation, you can save yourself the work of looking into the image contents.

Comment: @user3749485 yes, possibly I guess if there were two images that were exactly the same but had different file formats. If the files are of the same format, I don't think so but I can't say for 100% certain.

Comment: so i want my application work without dependance on the file format and for that i want to look at image content

Comment: @user3749485, be aware that many image formats are lossy, so for instance if you convert a PNG to a JPEG, the pixel data won't be exactly the same; the JPEG will be just an approximation of the PNG.  The same goes for loading a JPEG and saving it as a different JPEG.  Each time you save via a lossy algorithm, more information is lost and the less the exported image matches the original.

Comment: @adv12 as i understand from  you that i need way to compare the two array to likely equal not exactly eqaul ,, is that true ??!

Comment: @user3749485, If you're going to be comparing images in a lossy file format to their originals, then yes, you'll need some way to find images that are "like" each other (same dimensions, pixel values "nearly equal", etc.)  But I don't think the comparison logic will be trivial.

Comment: @Adv12 so do you have a way to implement it or any idea to do it ?!
oh and thanks for your suggestion about LockBit it work as perfect

Comment: Nope, I don't have any idea how to do it.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

After convert Image to Bitmap, translucensy have value 255 for all pixels...