# db.mdf is being used by another process

Tags: c#, filestream, localdb, file-locking

Right now by code looks like the following:

```
private void DatabaseIntegrityCheck()
{
    try
    {
        string m_checksum;
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\~\db.mdf"))
        {
            SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
            m_checksum = BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(m_checksum);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("unable to retrieve checksum");

    }

}
```

When I set a breakpoint in my code to see what the exception is, I get a IOException that says:

The process cannot access the file 'db.mdf' because it is being used by another process.

The way I am running the checksum is there's a button in my window and when I click it, the method above is being called to perform the action. I want to check and see if it works first, so I just Console.WriteLine the checksum hash but the exception above is being thrown.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Would it be right to guess that the file is in use by your own application, because you have a connection to that database open? If so, you need to close your connection. If not, then you need to work out what application *is* accessing the database file, and close it.

Comment: @DanPuzey, Yeah in my application, that's the database for it. I want to run an integrity check on my database that my application is using. In my server explorer under Data Connections, the database is not listed. So the connection should be closed.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have code accessing the database anywhere?

Comment: I might but how do I close that? Do you mean that I need to close my using block for db?

Comment: Also what if I need that code to access the db? Is there another way to check db with it throwing that exception?

Comment: You can't open the file if it's already locked elsewhere. When you say "check db," what do you mean? The SHA you're currently trying to calculate is going to change every time you write to the database, so I'm not sure what value you're getting out of it.

Comment: Good point. Can you give me an example of what could be running in the background accessing the db? In this viewmodel, I am displaying system paths saved in db, could that be it?

Comment: Could it due to memory leaks in my code?

Comment: Well what kind of database is it, to start with? ("Normal" SQL Server with a database server running permanently in the background? SQL Express?)

Comment: SQL Server Express Localdb

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041599/how-do-i-debug-this-error-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-x-because-it-is-b

Comment: @usr, I was thinking could I perform a database checksum before on beginning the application or closing the application so that the data does not change during either step? This would be done in app.xaml? This would prevent database from being accessed by another file right? Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
        try
        {
            string mChecksum;
            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"E:\draft.pdf"))
            {
                var sha = new SHA256Managed();
                var cs = new CryptoStream(stream, sha, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                byte[] hash = sha.Hash;

                mChecksum = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", String.Empty);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(mChecksum);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("unable to retrieve checksum");

        }
```

See details about [CryptoStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Does not address the question.

Comment: What does FlushFinalBlock() do?