# How do I debug this error? "The process cannot access the file X because it is being used by another process"

Tags: .net, winapi, filesystems

I am using a file system API (in .NET or a native one) to try to open a file. I receive the following error message:

> The process cannot access the file X because it is being used by another process.

What does this error mean and how can I debug it?

Answer (score 2):

**What this error means:**

This error means that you are trying to open a file that is already opened with conflicting access and sharing settings.

The message is misleading because the file is not necessarily opened by a different process. This is a Win32-level exception. It just means that there is another *handle* opened for that file.

This error is also applicable to directories.

**How to debug it:**

Find out what process or component in your application opened the file and did not yet close it. You can use Sysinternals Process Explorer's "Find Handle" feature to find the offending process and close the handle.

If your own code opened the handle there is no general procedure to find the problem. Review your code. Comment code until the error goes away.

**Common mistakes are:**

- Leaking a `FileStream`: `File.Open(path); //leak!`
- Not wrapping resources in a `using` statement. In most cases disposable resources should we wrapped in `using`.
- Having the file open in some app, like:

  - A text editor
  - A development tool
  - A database server
  - A Windows Explorer Window with the respective file selected
  - A Command Prompt Window that has the respective directory set as the current directory

**How to fix:**

Close other applications using that file. Make sure that you close your file handles when you are done with them. Use the `using` statement.

Comment: What's a process explorer? Is it already built in .NET? I don't want to download another program. Is there a way to check in .NET or on a program that already comes with Windows 7?

Comment: @KalaJ nothing built-in, alas.

Comment: Opps sorry, wrong context. Will delete and post in my question.

Answer (score 0):

- or it could be that a developer tool you are using has the file open like  a database query tool?
- or you have a explorer window open and the file selected
- or command line cd-ed to a folder that your interacting with.