# String Comparison Length Mismatch

Tags: c#, string, md5

I am comparing two strings, one String I receive from a server with 32 characters with another one I calculate with the following code:

```
string getMd5(string fileName)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "‌​").ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that even when the two strings seems identical, the comparison fails because the string returned by the function above contains more characters than the one I receive. Please, see picture attached:

[image]

So, how do I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: It does not look like it contains more characters. How do you know?

Comment: @FirstStep Can you see the `currentMd5.Length`? How is this possible? You see and count 32 characters, but the length says there are 62, hence comparison fails.

Comment: Are you sure that the encoding of text read from both the files is the same?

Comment: @FirstStep, see the `Length` value in attached watch pic

Comment: Now I see it sorry. I would compare just the first 32 then (whatever currentMd5 size) or just check if currentMd5 exists in the second string. Not the best approach

Comment: Why are you converting the outputs to strings instead of comparing the `byte[]` directly?

Comment: @FirstStep That assumes that the different character is at the end, and not at the start or in the middle.

Comment: It is probably the encoding, the stream using Unicode.

Comment: I don't think it's the encoding because C# `string` is all the same encoding.  Any `int` is the same as another other, right? Shouldn't any `string` be the same as any other? I'm wondering if there is possibly exactly 30 dashes and this is somehow messing it up: `.Replace("-", "‌​")`

Comment: @Lee Because the app receives the `MD5` as a `String`, hence I calculate the File `MD5` and convert it to `String` to make the comparison.

Comment: I'll bet Convert.ToString is using Unicode to encode the string, which would double the byte count. Try using new UTF8Encoding().GetString instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the `"‌​"` in your code actually contains an two invisible Unicode characters - a ['ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER' (U+200C)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) and a ['ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). My guess is that they got there because at some point the source code fragment went through a word processor such as Word or the like. Use `string.Empty` or have a free one - `""`.

Comment: Then why do all of these return `0` for length? `("" + "").Length`,
                `"ab".Replace("a", "").Replace("b", "").Length`,
                `"ab".Replace("a", "").Replace("b", "").ToLower().Length`

Comment: @Quantic - that's because "your" empty strings are actually empty strings. Copy them to Notepad and save them as Unicode (which is actually UTF-16LE in MS lingo) - the file sizes will be the number of double quotes times two. Then copy the ostensibly empty string from the question and save the file - you'll see that the file is actually 8 bytes - 4 for the two quotes and 4 for the two invisible characters. Let me dig up what those characters actually are...

Comment: @Quantic use the "‌​" that **seems** like an empty string in question. (or  try this code `var xx = "‌​".Length;)`

Comment: Ok you're right when I copy OP's `""` it has 2 invisible characters in it. To @EdPlunkett's point, how did this happen? Did OP copy and paste `""` from somewhere instead of just typing it from his keyboard into the editor?

Comment: @EdPlunkett `var bytes = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("‌​"));`    http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128

Comment: for reference: the zero-width-characters are probably from copying the [top comment from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520086/1761622). Somehow the commenter got invisible unicode characters into his "empty" string