# DateTime string conversion with both full month name and AM/PM

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I know similar questions have been asked such as here: [DateTime string conversion with both month name and AM/PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645259/datetime-string-conversion-with-both-month-name-and-am-pm)

Indeed, I am having a very similar problem but even when I follow the answers to the question above it still doesn't seem to work for me. 
I'm trying to execute the following piece of code:

```
dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString + " " + yearString + " " + 
timeString, "MMMM dd yyyy HH:mm tt", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Where 'dateString' is "September 25"
'yearstring' is "2017"
'timestring' is "6:30 PM"

The Exception that gets thrown when executing this code is FormatException String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. In my date string above I am inserting a single white space for each use of quotes.

Comment: Post the dateString as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help

Comment: Use `h` instead of `HH`. `HH` is the 24-hour-clock hour, so it makes little sense to use it in conjunction with `tt`. I very much doubt that the full month name has anything to do with this.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, however, I've made that change and am still getting the error.

Comment: @andy_coder `DateTime.ParseExact("September 25 2017 6:30 PM", "MMMM dd yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` just works fine. Your error (you didn't _even_ mentioned what it was exactly) might come somewhere else. Also it would be better to check your string(s) doesn't have _any_ invisible character using with a unicode explorer.

Comment: Please show that in the question then, ideally in the form of a [mcve] - there's no need to do string concatenation when you can just show the example with the complete hard-coded string.

Comment: So I just got it to work. Your comment, @SonerGönül, might of helped me. I made 2 changes. I changed H to lower case h and I created the full date time string first in a new varaible and then passed that in the datetime.parseexact() function.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by doing two things (probably the second item more relevant). I changed upper case H in my format string to lower case h. Additionally I saved the full date time string first in a separate variable and then passed that in to the DateTime.ParseExact() function. Maybe other users can answer **WHY** this worked.

Thanks Stack Overflow community.