# Why is the absolute path used to read text files in C #, and the path will change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use unity3d and vs2019 to read a text file (txt) as follows：

```cs
    public class MeshTest01 : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        string filePath = @"‪‪‪D:\Desktop\Unity\Mesh\77.txt";
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        foreach (var item in lines)
        {
            Debug.Log(item);
        }
        //List<string> planesStr = TxtOperation.GetFaces2str(linesStr);
        //Debug.Log(TxtOperation.GetFaceIndex(planesStr[0]));

    }
}
```

The error information is as follows：

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "E:\project\GitHub\RobotSimulation\***D:\Desktop\Unity\Mesh\77.txt".
```

[image]

Why does the previous part of the file path appear

Comment: Did you paste the value of `filePath` from a document with mixed text direction?  At the beginning of the string literal, after `@"` and before `D:`, you have the bytes `e2 80 aa` — the (unprintable) "Left-to-Right Embedding" character — repeated three times.  As a result, `filePath` starts with something other than a drive letter so `ReadAllLines()` treats it as a relative path.  To fix this, delete and retype the beginning of the string literal.  This same type of problem happened recently in [C# error in reading file from another hard drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62704900/150605).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read text file return 'System.NotSupportedException' exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278233/read-text-file-return-system-notsupportedexception-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I can't explain why this happens.

Usually yes, this would be one way of how to read an external file.

My guess would be that since your file is placed on a different drive the project might be sandboxed and therefore interprets the path as a relative one. Never tried to load files from different drives to be honest.

---

However, in general I would keep the files together with the project they belong to and place them

- either in the [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html) in the editor in the folder [`Assets/StreamingAssets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) for files that shall be

  - read/write able for the editor
  - but readonly later in a build
- or the [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) for builds if you want to

  - write to them via code
  - or let the user change the content
    externally afterwards

Then you would get your path using

```
var path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "SomeFolder", "77.txt");
```

or accordingly

```
var path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "SomeFolder", "77.txt");
```

---

For the streaming assets there are some special cases (e.g. on Android) where you need to read the file using [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) since it gets compressed.

---

Alternatively if it is an option for you you could also directly drag it into the `Assets` (or any folder below except special ones like `StreamingAssets`, `Resources` etc) and then directly drag it into a field via the Inspector using it as a (read-only) [`TextAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html)

```
[SerializeField] private TextAsset meshFile;
```

and later access it's content via

```
var lines = meshFile.text.Split('/n');
```

---

Also I general: You should make a huge circle around the `Resources`!

Unity themselves strongly recommend to **not** use it! This and the reasons can be found in the [Best practices](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7).

Comment: Thank you. Here is the code I wrote according to your suggestion![](https://gitee.com/fenghezhi/Pictures/raw/master/img/20200714151150.png)

Comment: @风何之 This would require that you put the file in `Assets/StreamingAssets/TextMesh/77.txt`