# C# MD5 hashing in hashset

Tags: c#, hash, md5

I am relatively new to c#. I am currently learning on hashset and understand that hashset do not allow an identical element inside the hashset. My question is am i able to hash the files in my directory with md5 hash and store them in a hashset so that i can check for the duplicated hash or files in a way?

Comment: @Viv there is n method for Encryption and Decryption in C#. snippet your code if you stuck anywhere

Comment: Beware of [pigeonholes](https://blog.codinghorror.com/hashtables-pigeonholes-and-birthdays/). Also a hashset and MD5 are similar but different. Checking for equality is a two step workflow. First, you check if the hash of two things is equal. If it is not, you can be pretty sure, the things are different. But you can **NOT** be sure that they are equal. For that, you would need to perform a deeper equality check. For files, you'd probably have to compare each byte. So hashing is used to quickly weed out a lot of definite "not equals".

Comment: See also [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/)

Comment: @John MD5 produces a 128-bit hash value. (same size as guid) so it would be extremely unlikely that two different files would generate the same hash.

Comment: @Magnus Indeed it's unlikely, but it's an important distinction, especially if OP applies the same logic to hashes that result in smaller results in future.

Comment: @John so unlikely that if processing  6 billion files per second for 100 years you might have a collision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` Class is a collection of unique elements. The namespace for the HashSet class is **System.Collections.Generic**. It was introduced in **.NET 3.5**.

Let take an example with files:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HashSet<string> FileData = new HashSet<string>();
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
         using (var stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\FolderTest\\Document.txt"))
         {
              var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
              var data = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
              FileData.Add(data);
         }
         using (var stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\FolderTest\\Document.txt"))
         {
              var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
              var data = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
              FileData.Add(data);
         }
         using (var stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\FolderTest\\Document2.txt"))
         {
              var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
              var data = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
              FileData.Add(data);
         }
    }
    foreach (var file in FileData)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(file);
    } 
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

In the code above we create a simple HashSet type of `HashSet<string>` and adding the string to it. 
Given above, even though we try to add a duplicate string of hash data, we will not get any error but when we iterate the collection, we cannot find the string.

> How you compare the results afterward is up to you; you can convert
>   the byte array to base64 for example, or compare the bytes directly.
>   (Just be aware that arrays don't override Equals. Using base64 is
>   simpler to get right, but slightly less efficient if you're really
>   only interested in comparing the hashes.) [see these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520048/calculate-md5-checksum-for-a-file)

**Characteristics of HashSet**:

- When we add elements to `HashSet<T>` automatically increases
  the capacity of HashSet.
- It is used in a situation where we want to prevent duplicates from
  being inserted in the collection.
- HashSet provides many mathematical set operations, such as set
  addition (unions) and set subtraction.