# What is the easiest way to obtain `byte[]` from `BlazorInputFile.IFileStream`

Tags: c#, .net, md5, blazor, blazorinputfile

I have a file that a user will select in their browser using [BlazorInputFile](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorInputFile) as expounded by [Steve Sanderson](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/).

Once selected I want to calculate a checksum for the file using `System.Security.Cryptography.MD5`, similar to what's described in this answer to **[Calculate MD5 checksum for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520086/1011722)**.

However, I encounter a `System.NotSupportedException` when I try this:

```cs
private string GetMd5ForFile(IFileListEntry file)
{
   using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
   {
      return Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(this.file.Data));
   }
}
```

Some exception details are:

```
 > Message: "Synchronous reads are not supported"
 > Source : "BlazorInputFile"
 > Stack  : "at BlazorInputFile.FileListEntryStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)"
```

I know that `ComputeHash()` takes an array of `byte`. I've so far tried  to cast BlazorInputFile's streams to familiar types or to read the bytes to an array with a method of its own `FileStream`, but without success.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```cs
private async Task<string> GetMd5ForFile(IFileListEntry file) {
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create()) {
        var data = await file.ReadAllAsync();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(data.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not satisfy your own question's title...

Comment: Indeed. It's the only answer I've got, so far, to the scenario as a whole.  It's hoped better information will come along. The title reflects the way the problem presented to me as a working programmer and so might occur to others that way — but neither answer nor title is perfect. Just accepted. "Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally." Thanks for your input. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer