# Code for check compare files in different directories are same or different using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, directory, c#-2.0

I have 2 directories ..I need to check that in two directories the files exist is same or not..if there is difference in files then move that files from first directory to second directoy..how can  i implement?

Comment: This is a bit too open ended question. Which part of this are you having trouble?

Comment: i created 2 array for store file names from the directory..

Comment: "i created 2 array for store file names from the directory" ok please post this code. How do you compare the content of the suspicious file?

Comment: Are you sure you can't use [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) for this? `robocopy /xc /xn /xo /mov source destination `

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
        private void CopyMissedFiles(string source, string destination)
        {
            var sourceDir = new DirectoryInfo(source);
            var destinationDir = new DirectoryInfo(destination);
            var sourceFiles = sourceDir.GetFiles();
            var destinationFiles = destinationDir.GetFiles();
            foreach (var file in sourceFiles.Where(x => destinationFiles.All(y => y.Name != x.Name)))
            {
                file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destinationDir.FullName, file.Name));
            }
        }
```

**Update:**
if you need to compare the file content, you can use MD5 hash to do that. Here is the description, how to calculate the hash [Calculate MD5 checksum for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520048/calculate-md5-checksum-for-a-file)

Comment: thanks for valuable response..i will try