# Choose the newest file from each directory

Tags: c#

I am using this to choose a root folder and take the newest file from each directory before adding this files into my `listbox` but in some cases it does not choose the newest file.

```
var rootDirFile = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(pathToSearch, "*.doc", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .OrderByDescending(f => File.GetLastWriteTime(f))
    .Take(1);

var allNewestFilesOfEachFolder = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(pathToSearch, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(d => Directory.EnumerateFiles(d, "*.doc")
        .OrderByDescending(f => File.GetLastWriteTime(f))
        .FirstOrDefault());

foreach (string tempFile in rootDirFile.Concat(allNewestFilesOfEachFolder))
{
    //add the file
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use GetCreationTime instead of GetLastWriteTime

Comment: According to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360324/checking-when-a-file-was-last-modified-in-c-sharp-on-windows-os that is the way to go.

Comment: Are you looking for the last created file or the last modified one?

Comment: last created file but i can see that GetCreationTime() solve my problem, is it the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

`File.GetLastWriteTime` [Is not always reliable on WindowsVista/7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992223/file-getlastwritetime-seems-to-be-returning-out-of-date-value) (see my answer in this post) as it could seem.

To create more reliable solution, you may use think about [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx), but in that case you would need to use some kind of running service.

Or can think about use if [File.GetCreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime.aspx), if that "new" files are actually created every time.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using this for a while and don't seem to have any problems.

We can't use `File.GetCreationTime` since edits are made in files regardless of creation time.

```
while (Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Count() > 7)
  {
     DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
     FileSystemInfo fileInfo = dirInfo.GetFileSystemInfos().OrderBy(fileT => fileT.LastWriteTime).First();
     File.Delete(fileInfo.FullName);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a list of directory/latest file pairs:

```
var latestByDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(_strPath)
    .GetDirectories()
    .Select(d => new
    {
         Directory = d,
        LatestFile = d.GetFiles()
            .OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime)
            .DefaultIfEmpty((FileInfo)null)
            .ToList().First()
    });
```