# Order files/list before binding them to gridview asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Hi I have something like the code below, I want to sort/order the files in the folder lets say by name of the file in asc or dsc order, before binding to the gridview:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
                    List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();

                foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                {
                    files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
                }
           
                GridView1.DataSource = files;
                GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Do you need to sort in the list or physically ?

Comment: @Muhammad in the list only so that when I bind it to the gridview they will appear in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply order by after foreach loop

```
 files = files.OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
```

For Order by descending

```
files = files.OrderByDescending(x => x.Text).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you. If I wanted now to order them by last modified how that would be possible?

Comment: You need to get last modified time for each file and then sort it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360324/check-last-modified-date-of-file-in-c-sharp