# Read created last modified time-stamp of a file using C#

Tags: c#, file-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Modified date from file in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185378/how-to-get-modified-date-from-file-in-c-sharp)

How do you, Read created / last modified time-stamp of a file, using C#?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From: http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-creation-modification-time/

```
// local times
DateTime creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(@"c:\file.txt");
DateTime lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"c:\file.txt");
DateTime lastAccessTime = File.GetLastAccessTime(@"c:\file.txt");

// UTC times
DateTime creationTimeUtc = File.GetCreationTimeUtc(@"c:\file.txt");
DateTime lastWriteTimeUtc = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(@"c:\file.txt");
DateTime lastAccessTimeUtc = File.GetLastAccessTimeUtc(@"c:\file.txt");

// write file last modification time (local / UTC)
Console.WriteLine(lastWriteTime);     // 9/30/2007 2:16:04 PM
Console.WriteLine(lastWriteTimeUtc);  // 9/30/2007 6:16:04 PM
```

Answer (score 3):

See [System.IO.FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx).

```
   var info = new FileInfo(@"C:\thefile.txt");    
   var created = info.CreationTime;    
   var modified = info.LastWriteTime;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace getLastTimeStamp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\getLastTimeStamp\Program.cs");

            Console.WriteLine(info.CreationTime.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(info.LastWriteTime.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```